# Django Import Class From models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Using a folder structure like this:

```
library/
-django.wsgi
-manage.py
-static/
    --all my static files
-library/
    --__init__.py
    --models.py
    --settings.py
    --urls.py
    --views.py
    --wsgi.py
    --templates/
        ---where i plan to store all my templates
```

How can i import a class in my views.py that is defined in models.py?

I've tried:

```
from . import models.class

from models import class

from projectname.models import class

from projectname import models.class

from project import class
```

But for all those i get invalid syntax errors

views.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.contrib.auth import logout

from library.models import 7DTagmap
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class 7DTagmap(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tag_id = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    st_tag_id = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = '7d_tagmap'
```

error:

```
invalid syntax (views.py, line 11)
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    invalid syntax (views.py, line 11)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use:

```
from library.models import MyClass
```

and you should be good to go :)

(the basic structure is `from <app>.models import <ModelName>`)

**update:**

the problem is (almost!) certainly that your model begins with '7' -- change it to a letter character, and all will be well, I'm (almost!) sure :)

Comment: I don't really have a project app structure though. Just a project.

Comment: you do... you have a project named `library`, and within it an app named `library`...

Comment: Ok i see what you mean. So this should work: from library.models import 7DTagmap but it doesn't so i must be missing something.

Comment: i think maybe we need to see more code -- could you update your question to show your `models.py` and your `views.py`, please?

Comment: Awesome definitely that. I tried that but didn't think it worked because i got another error but having a detailed look at the other error revealed that it was complaining about the other models that begin with numbers. Smh company's that begin with numbers in their. Thanks!

Comment: In Python - any identifier (variable or class name), can only begin with a letter or an underscore `_`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- that's correct.  `PEP8` stipulates that class names should begin with an uppercase letter too, if memory serves.

Comment: Its not just PEP8, its in the [lexer for python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

Answer (score 3):

for example in your `models.py` you got :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class register(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Then in your `views.py`, you can call like this :

```
from library.models import register
```

Comment: Tried this: from library.models import 7DTagmap and that didn't work

Comment: I used djangos inspectdb and it generated that as the class name

Comment: Error added to question